# Vue JS Encoding is changed in child components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, model-view-controller, utf-8

I have been looking for the solution for quite a long time, i decided to post my question here.

My problem is that in child components, special characters are being displayed as ��������, but in parent component it seems to be working fine and I don't have any clue whats the root cause of this.

I am routing from one component to another and i saw that in source code my meta data are read only like that:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTOUt.png)

I believe that it may be changed after routing and set to default encoding.
Is there any way of correcting this?

Any helps would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Everything should be UTF-8 and this should just work. You shouldn't need a charset declaration on any div, but there [should be one either](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations) configured on the server so present in the headers of every response, or in a meta in the head...

```
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
```

Check the encoding of the source files of the problem components in a programmer's text editor. This should also be utf8.